# Best way to call rest APIs with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I need to call various API methods on server with Ajax. There are some methods that return sets of server objects, some methods that update objects, some methods that don't directly work with objects but update some properties on them (like count, checkins etc.)

Stores solve lots of problems when it comes to data binding but I can't find an object oriented approach to create a client-side repository that works with server side api methods. Should I create a new class and fill it with methods that make Ajax calls to server or should I extend stores to include new Ajax methods?

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a separate class and use functions, that is fine. But generally people use Sencha controllers for the same. I hope you have a controller. Why don't you put the methods in the respective controller?

Comment: Using stores for databinding and controllers for other ajax operations seems a little strange to me. When it comes to pull model data from the server we use stores but when updating only some of the properties or related properties of multiple models we have to make ajax calls and this feels a little inconvenient.